# How can I call functions conditionally in function chaining?

Tags: javascript

I don't know what it's called, but in the canvas library i'm using you apply filters to a texture by calling

```
canvas.draw(texture).filter1().filter2().filter3().filter4();
```

and i'm trying to only draw certain filters if the value is not default, but i can't do it with regular if statements since the texture can only be set once, and if i try to set it again, the previous filter will get reset.

What i'm wondering is if i can somehow add "if" statements to the "train" of filters, like so:

```
canvas.draw(texture).if(something){filter1()}.if(somethingelse){filter2()}.if(something){filter3()};
```

and so on.

Sorry if i'm not very clear, i dont know what the filter "train" is called, where you apply filter after eachother on one line.

Comment: It's usually called **method chaining**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construct you have shown in the question is called, *function chaining*. The function `filter1`, `filter2`, ... `filterN` would just modify the same canvas object and return the same object at the end of the function.

You can very well include `if` conditions, like this

```
var canvasObject = canvas.draw(texture);

if (condition1) {
    canvasObject = canvasObject.filter1();
}

if (condition2) {
    canvasObject = canvasObject.filter2();
}

...
```

A simple example for the same, would look something like this

```
function Canvas() {

    actualCanvas = "";

    return {
        filter1: function() {
            actualCanvas += "filter1 ";
            return this;               // return the same object
        },
        filter2: function() {
            actualCanvas += "filter2 ";
            return this;               // return the same object
        },
        filter3: function() {
            actualCanvas += "filter3 ";
            return this;               // return the same object
        },
        getActualCanvas: function() {
            return actualCanvas;
        }
    }
}
```

And invoke the functions, like this

```
var canvasObject = new Canvas();

if (1 === 1) {
    canvasObject = canvasObject.filter1();
}

if (1 !== 1) {
    canvasObject = canvasObject.filter2();
}

if (2 === 2) {
    canvasObject = canvasObject.filter3();
}

console.log(canvasObject.getActualCanvas());
// filter1 filter3 

console.log(new Canvas().filter1().filter2().filter3().getActualCanvas());
// filter1 filter2 filter3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i've been stuck on this issue now for 2 weeks, and this just fixed it for me. I just made the canvas.draw(texture) into an object, and then applied to filters onto that. Thank you!